# Issue finding widget in list of widgets on device

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created an android widget that I am trying to run on a real device. My Android Manifest is this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver android:name=".AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidet.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff"/>

</receiver>

<activity android:name=".WidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>     
</intent-filter>

</activity>   

</application>

</manifest>
```

I originally got the error that no launcher activity was found so I set up the Launch Action in my Run Configurations to Launch my WidgetConfig activity. This fixed the issue but the application would stop unexpectedly.

Without changing my Launch Action (Launching Default Activity), I would of course get the original no launcher found error. My app widget would then be installed to the device.

Here is the other issue: the widget doesn't show up in the list of widgets when I long click on the homescreen but I know it is on the device because it shows up in the Application Manager list.

ALSO, I have tried to add the Launcher activity in the manifest but I was corrected being told that I didn't need it. If I really do need it can someone please tell me where to put it in my Manifest?

What is the issue?

ADDED:

Logcat error when adding widget to homescreen:

```
10-05 21:26:54.380: D/AndroidRuntime(18023): Shutting down VM
10-05 21:26:54.380: W/dalvikvm(18023): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2012)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1101)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2003)
10-05 21:26:54.390: E/AndroidRuntime(18023):    ... 10 more
```

ADDED UPDATED ERROR LOG AFTER ADDING

```
<activity android:name=".AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

to Manifest:

```
10-05 21:51:45.485: D/AndroidRuntime(3557): Shutting down VM
10-05 21:51:45.485: W/dalvikvm(3557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1746)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1854)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1041)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

its a spelling mistake within `<receiver> ...</receiver>`

**** you forgot to add g in appwidget

```
 <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
```

Try it and let me know ;)

And for Launcher error

try adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

within `<activity><intent-filter>...</intent-filter></activity>`

Comment: I still get the "No launcher activity found" error, but now it shows up in the list of widgets on the device (the second time around that I installed it after uninstalling it so I could reinstall it with the correction) I got a log error when I tried to add it to my home screen (updated question)

Comment: are you sure AFBWidget class been added to src?if so try updating manifest with com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget  logcat says it no class found exception

Comment: Luckily the widget shows up in the widget list now though just now says that my widget has stopped unexpectedly when I add it to the homescreen

Comment: Yeah AFBWidget is in src...I'll add it to the manifest and let you know

Comment: It does the same thing but with new error log (I think) please check the updated question >>has been updated

Comment: I've created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205341/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity) if that would be easier

Comment: @user1628978 ok.added answer there.