# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to Instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a widget but when I run it I get this error in the console:

```
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] ------------------------------
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Android Launch!
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Performing sync
[2013-10-05 22:02:56 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-10-05 22:03:00 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Uploading AwesomeFileBuilderWidget.apk onto device 'HT18YMA05067'
[2013-10-05 22:03:00 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Installing AwesomeFileBuilderWidget.apk...
[2013-10-05 22:03:04 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Success!
[2013-10-05 22:03:04 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] \AwesomeFileBuilderWidget\bin\AwesomeFileBuilderWidget.apk installed on device
[2013-10-05 22:03:04 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Done!
```

But the widget installs fine on my device and shows up in the Widget selection screen.

The second error occurs when I try to put my widget on the homescreen. I get this error in LogCat:

```
10-05 21:51:45.485: D/AndroidRuntime(3557): Shutting down VM
10-05 21:51:45.485: W/dalvikvm(3557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1746)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:1854)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1041)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
10-05 21:51:45.505: E/AndroidRuntime(3557):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver android:name=".AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff"/>

</receiver>

<activity android:name=".WidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />     
</intent-filter> 

</activity>   

<activity android:name=".AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

I have made sure I have checked all the boxes in the Order and Export section. I have also made sure that my AFBWidget and WidgetConfig classes are in src. (Please note that the actual widget configuration is in the correct xml location, the WidgetConfig.java is something else)

What is the issue?

Updated LogCat:

```
10-05 22:47:40.628: D/AndroidRuntime(4113): Shutting down VM
10-05 22:47:40.628: W/dalvikvm(4113): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1746)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1854)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1041)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
10-05 22:47:40.638: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     ... 11 more
```

ADDED CLASSES AND XML FILES:
AFBWidget.java:

```
import java.util.Random;

import com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.R;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AFBWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomInt = r.nextInt(1000000000);
    String rand = String.valueOf(randomInt);

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int awID = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.tvwidgetUpdate, rand);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, v);
    }

}
```

WidgetConfig.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.R;


public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText info;
AppWidgetManager awm;
Context c;
int awID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c = WidgetConfig.this;
    info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etwidgetconfig);
    //Getting info about the widget that launched this Activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
                );
    }else{
        finish();
    }
    awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String e = info.getText().toString();

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, e);

    Intent in = new Intent(c, WidgetConfig.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bwidgetOpen, pi);

    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

    finish();
}


}
```

Widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvConfigInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bwidgetOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwidgetUpdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

WidgetConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etwidgetconfig"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="@string/user_input_application_name">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bwidgetconfig"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ok" />

</LinearLayout>
```

App Widget Provider (app_stuff.xml):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FINALLY FIXED IT AFTER 3 DAYS! Ok, so it was indeed because my two java classes were in a default package. So to fix that, since my classes were being accessed via a different package, I created a new package that was my app (com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget) and then moved the classes into there and now it works with no problemos! :DD Thanks for all you've done I really do apperciate it! – user1628978

Answer (score 1):

try to clean your workspace. Goto Project->Clean and select your project. For some reason eclipse doesn't build manifest automatically.

and also try to clean you server by doing right click and then clean

Comment: I cleaned both and restarted eclipse and then cleaned again. I also made sure I completely reinstalled my widget on my device by unistalling it and then having eclipse reintall it when I ran my widget, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: if you are using third party jars, have you added them into library folder Go to Properties/ Java Build Path/ Libraries/ Add External JARs.

Comment: I haven't added any external JARs to the project yet and don't need to use any except for the original android.jar for my classes at this point

Comment: Just to be safe though I did add the support v7 jar to my project (for future use as well) but it didn't do anything

Comment: if you have lib structure then rename it to libs

Comment: If you mean the folder, then it's marked as libs, if not let me know. Sorry for all the fuss

Comment: ya I meant lib folder only right now I cant think of any other problem try checking logs

Comment: Hmm.. I added an updated logcat from running the widget now to see if anything has changed (I did clean and reinstall before I ran the widget to make sure)

Comment: Would the change from 3557 to 4113 mean anything? (ya just kind of winging it but you never know!)

Comment: I FINALLY FIXED IT AFTER 3 DAYS! Ok, so it was indeed because my two java classes were in a default package. So to fix that, since my classes were being accessed via a different package, I created a new package that was my app (com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget) and then moved the classes into there and now it works with no problemos! :DD Thanks for all you've done I really do apperciate it!

Comment: @user1628978 happy to help, you can add this as an answer to your question so that others can see what was the problem

Answer (score 1):

add all activities in src to AndroidManifest.xml.clean and run project then

Comment: My WidgetConfig.java and AFBWidget.java are the only classes I have besides xml files and the Appwidget provider at the moment so I should have them all in the manifest

Comment: i hope its WidgetConfig alone right and not My WidgetConfig.java(included my)

Comment: Right just "WidgetConfig"

Comment: ok.but from logcat i understand that the problem occurs only when activity file hasn't been added to manifest file

Comment: Oh I see what you mean but...how is that so? I mean.. I did add WidgetConfig.java to the Manifest correctly right?..

Comment: I would like to know for which class the widget been created,AFBWidget or WidgetConfig ?Also which class would you like to launch as soon as you install? can you post some screenshot?

Comment: I'll go ahead and post the coding for each component of my widget, that should clear up your question

Comment: I'm not sure what class I should launch when I install honestly

Comment: I FINALLY FIXED IT AFTER 3 DAYS! Ok, so it was indeed because my two java classes were in a default package. So to fix that, since my classes were being accessed via a different package, I created a new package that was my app (com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget) and then moved the classes into there and now it works with no problemos! :DD Thanks for all you've done I really do apperciate it!

Comment: @user1628978 I am happy to hear it.Good Luck